# Pinia: Can't import the named export 'computed' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia

i cant use Pinia in nuxt 2.15.8 and Vue 2.7.10 with Typescript, i tried many methods and installed many dependencies, but it just dont work, i tried so many things that i had to restart my main folders on githu; i installed this dependencies

```
 "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.9",
 "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
```

```
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@pinia/nuxt'
  ],
```

in build modules i try to use Pinia, but it dont work so now its empty:

```
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxtjs/fontawesome',
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],
```

this error Can't import the named export 'computed' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available) keeps showing

i solved this error one time, but then the nuxt didnt find the Pinia module, so i dont know what to do, i tried many ways but Pinia just dont run, someone was some idea? i converted my Nuxt to ts so my nuxt.config is .js not .ts, if it may interfere with this? im also using npm, im also getting this error sometimes:

```
 WARN  Module pinia is disabled due to incompatibility issues:                                                                                11:38:23 PM
 - [bridge] Nuxt bridge is required
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139484/nuxt-pinia-cant-import-the-named-export-computed-from-non-ecmascript-module

Answer (score 0):

The error was the version, i installed the newest Pinia version and it work perfectelly fine.