# Nuxt Pinia: Can't import the named export 'computed' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia

i cant use Pinia in nuxt 2.15.8 and Vue 2.7.10 with Typescript, i tried many methods and installed many dependencies, but it just dont work, i tried so many things that i had to restart my main folders on githu; i installed this dependencies

```
 "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.9",
 "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
```

in build modules i try to use Pinia, but it dont work so now its empty:

```
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxtjs/fontawesome',
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],
```

```
modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@pinia/nuxt'
  ],
```

i solved this error "Can't import the named export 'computed' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available) keeps showing" one time, but then the nuxt didnt find the Pinia module, so i dont know what to do, i tried many ways but Pinia just dont run, someone was some idea? i converted my Nuxt to ts so my nuxt.config is .js not .ts, if it may interfere with this? im also using npm, im also getting this error sometimes:

```
 WARN  Module pinia is disabled due to incompatibility issues:                                                                                11:38:23 PM
 - [bridge] Nuxt bridge is required
```

someone knows how to solve it? i just wanna run Pinia in my nuxt project

Comment: add your tsconfig.json to the post